# Remove Config data from JSON output of NIFI InvokeHTTP calling its own API for all processors info

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am able to use NIFI InvokeHTTP to call its own API for all processor info and push that along.   I am having no luck removing the Config Array with a JOLT Transform in between InvokeHTTP and my output processor.

Input Data

```
{
    "processors": [{
        "id": "891dcf62-016d-1000-1727-961e4e3c2f7a",
        "props": "dozens of other props here",
        "component": {
            "id": "891dcf62-016d-1000-1727-961e4e3c2f7a",
            "parentGroupId": "891dcf5c-016d-1000-0556-9e69f1934f95",
            "config": {
                "properties": "100s of lengthy properties"
            },
            "componentProps": "dozen or so others"
        },
        "inputRequirement": "INPUT_REQUIRED"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "891dcf62-016d-1000-1727-961e4e3c2f7b",
        "props": "dozens of other props here",
        "component": {
            "id": "891dcf62-016d-1000-1727-961e4e3c2f7b",
            "parentGroupId": "891dcf5c-016d-1000-0556-9e69f1934f96",
            "config": {
                "properties": "100s of lengthy properties"
            },
            "componentProps": "dozen or so others"
        },
        "inputRequirement": "INPUT_REQUIRED"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I didn't see **Config Array** in posted JSON.

Comment: Show us your jolt config.

Comment: {
 "operation": "remove",
 "spec": {
  "processors": {
   "*": {
    "component": {
     "*": {
      "config": {
       "*": ""
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Only sort works for me in Nifi 1.9.2 Jolt Transform Processor Advanced (test) form.  I most want to remove entire config object-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You went too deep with yours spec. Here is modified:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "processors": {
        "*": {
          "component": {
            "config": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems logical unfortunately I am still getting the Validation Failed - Please verify the provided specification.   I'm guessing that Nifi's Jolt Transform Processor's Advanced-Tester Form doesn't work.  I used my example input and your spec and got that.

Comment: I have confirmed that your spec works.   I ran it on http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Comment: I have confirmed that the Examples at http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception with Arrays do not work in Nifi Jolt Transform Process